# Moonlight 3.99.0.3 is not compatiable with firefox 12?

Tags: moonlight

How I can uninstall and reinstall moonlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser reports that "moonlight" is "disabled" due to incompatibility, then here is what you need to do:

Make a backup copy of .mozilla (/home/your_user_name/.mozilla) before proceeding. This will preserve important bookmarks and other things you might want to consider later.

Now delete the .mozilla folder from /home/your_user_name/ and then reinstall all the addons and search plugins you had.

Now go to http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight and again install moonlight from there.

Note:

1) .mozilla is a hidden folder. Press (ctrl+h) to see it.

2) You can restore your bookmarks from backup of .mozilla

```
mozilla/firefox/om8xf96h.default/bookmarkbackups
```

This "om8xf96h" will look diffrent on your system. To restore open Bookmarks Window then use the  "Restore" option from "Import and Backup" menu. Click on Restore and then navigate to backup directory and select the last modified .json file (like "bookmarks-2012-05-02.json")

4) To restore search engines (search plugins) copy the "searchplugins" folder from mozilla/firefox/om8xf96h.default/ and paste it to /home/your_user_name/.mozilla/firefox/om8xf96h.default

Answer (score 0):

It seems that moonlight is discountinued for linux. You could force Firefox to enable moonlight but there are known security issues and youre at your own.

Comment: I have solved this issue. Now moonlight is working well.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice how did you solve it? You can post the solution as an answer to your own question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Actually you simply have to reinstall the MoonLight Add-on from the [web site](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx) and restart firefox to make it work again.

Comment: It did not worked that way. I tried it on the first hand.